# Timer On Certain Commands

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a reputation command with my bot but I want it on a 24-hour timer so they can only give reputation once a day. The first block they're only viewing their own rep, and if they mention a user it gives the mentioned user a rep point. I don't understand how to do the timer though...

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const ms = require("ms");
let reputation = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./saves/reputation.json", "utf8"));

module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args) => {
  console.log(`${message.member} ran the "reputation" command`);

  //-- Timer on last use
  let repTimer = 8640000

  //-- Getting username
  let repUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() ||
    message.guild.members.get(args[0]));

  //-- Only displaying your points --\\
  if (!repUser) {
    if (!reputation[message.author.id]) {
      reputation[message.author.id] = {
        reputation: 0
      };
    }

    let repPoints = reputation[message.author.id].reputation;

    let repEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setAuthor(message.author.username)
      .setColor("#00FF00")
      .setDescription(`Reputation Points: ${repPoints}`);

    message.channel.send(repEmbed);
  } //-- End !repUser
  else {

    if (!reputation[repUser.id]) {
      reputation[repUser.id] = {
        reputation: 0
      };
    }

    //-- If user was mentioned --\\
    let numRep = reputation[repUser.id].reputation;

    reputation[repUser.id] = {
      reputation: numRep + 1
    };

    message.channel.send(`${message.author.username} has given ${repUser} a 
    reputation point`);
  }

  //-- Needed (Also Wth Error Message) --\\
  fs.writeFile("./saves/reputation.json", JSON.stringify(reputation), (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err)
  });

}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "rep"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to have a separate file (for example `/saves/players.json`) in which you can store player objects.

First you'd read the file and see if it already has an object for said user, if it doesn't then you create a new one.

After that you see if the user can give rep and if so, you fire the code to give the reputation point. After that you reset the property so it can be used again in 24 hours.

Have a look at the code below. This isn't tested but it should give you  a general idea of what I'm trying to explain.

```js
let players = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./saves/players.json", 
"utf8"));

// Get the user who gave the rep
let repGiver;

if(!players[message.author.id]){
  repGiver = {
    nextRep: new Date()
  };

  players[message.author.id] = repGiver;
} else {
  repGiver = players[message.author.id];
}

// Check whether the user can give rep
if (repGiver.nextRep <= new Date()) {
  /*
   * Code to give a player rep
   */

  players[message.author.id] = {
    // Reset the nextRep property to tomorrow
    nextRep: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
  };
} else {
  // Code for when a player can't give rep yet
}

// Save the new values for players
fs.writeFile("./saves/players.json", JSON.stringify(players), (err) 
    => {
      if (err) console.log(err)
    });
```